# Validator not being applied on child property

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am creating a `POST` API which takes `Order` as input using `[FromBody]`. This `Order` has a `Buyer` property and both of these are being validated using `FluentValidation`. Following are the classes:

```
[Validator(typeof(OrderValidator))]
public class Order
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
}

[Validator(typeof(BuyerValidator))]
public class Buyer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Validators of these classes:

```
public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
{
    public OrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ProductId).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(x => x.Buyer).NotNull();
    }
}

public class BuyerValidator : AbstractValidator<Buyer>
{
    public BuyerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(3, 100);
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).Length(5, 100);
    }
}
```

Here, I am applying the validator using `Validator` attribute on both classes. It is working fine on `Order` class but not being executed on `Buyer` class. Do I have to set the validator for `Buyer` class in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend buyer validation like that:

```
public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
{
    public OrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.ProductId).GreaterThan(0);
        RuleFor(x => x.Buyer).NotNull().SetValidator(new BuyerValidator())
    }
}
```

Not tested it in real, found in docs [here](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/b.-Creating-a-Validator#complex-properties)